# Wordpress - plugin to list ONLY images USED on website?

Tags: wordpress, image, image-processing, plugins

I just started a project to revamp a wordpress website. On inspection, the site has **thousands** of images uploaded to the media library. One of the issues is that there are multiple variations of many of its images, i.e. same name but with a different size specified at the end. Also the file names are very long - a typical image has **80+** chars in the filename.

Ideally I want to just optimise the used images, and get rid of the unused (after taking a back-up of the original set)

Does anyone know of a wordpress plugin that would enable me to download either a list or a zip of only the images that are in use on the site?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin may help: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wow-media-library-fix/

If it doesn't handle everything, writing a shortcode that produced a list of files used that could then be compared to a list of all media files might also help.

At some point I'd consider removing all thumbnails and regenerating only the ones you've identified as in use. Several plugins are available for that purpose. You might then want to look at Media File Renamer https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-file-renamer/, before actually proceeding to regeneration, though it will also work in the opposite order.

Actually, figuring out what order to go in might be a significant part of the battle. Maybe: fix all or most obviously bad entries, remove thumbnails, rename files, optimize, then regenerate might be the most efficient - unless you're happy with one or another on-the-fly optimizer.